# What would 2>&1 do in command line

Tags: command-line

In the line `find /. -group bandit  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"`

what would the operators > and & actually be doing. I've found various pages explaining their uses. I'm not sure what > would do if it's not pointing to a file. Is & making the whole command run in the background, seeing as it's close to the end?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/71428/what-does-21-do-in-command-line

Comment: Thanks, is this considered a duplicate if that linked question is on stack exchange.

Comment: I don't think so but I have close-voted the question as "belongs on superuser.com"